# Dalvik in User Agent in Android 6.0

Tags: android, user-agent, dalvik

I have seen several times useragents like 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; vivo 1606 Build/MMB29M) and does not seem correct to me. As I understand it, Dalvik is the - now, discontinued - process of VM in Android versions 4.4 (KitKat) and earlier.

How it is possible to find an user agent with Dalvik coming from an Android with OS 6 (Marshmallow) if the Dalvik software it is not included in later versions of Android 4.4?

PS This community has been a great help in many occasions and finally I have registered. Always a pleasure.

Thank you so much,